# AngularJS ng-class doesn't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've got a problem with ng-class.

This is a piece of my **controller**

```
export class UIController
{
    public static $inject = [];

    public commands: Array<string> = ['showMap', 'showGantry', 'showSign'];
    public showMap: boolean = false;
    public showGantry: boolean = false;
    public showSign: boolean = false;
    public loadingMessage: string;

    constructor()
    {
        this.showMap = true;
    }

    public toggleContent(commandToExecute: string)
    {
        for (var command of this.commands) {
            if (command != commandToExecute) {
                this[command] = false;
            }
            else if (!this[command]) {
                this[command] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**directive** that is connected with it

```
class LeafletMap implements ng.IDirective
{
    public restrict: string = "A";
    public controller: string =  'UIController';
    
    public link = (scope, elem, attr) : void =>
    {
        scope.uiCtrl.loadingMessage = 'test'; 

        scope.$root.$on('details', (event: IAngularEvent, message: any) =>
        {
            scope.uiCtrl.toggleContent('showGantry');
        });
    };
    
}
```

and piece of HTML view:

```
<div class="accordion-button" data-ng-click="uiCtrl.toggleContent('showGantry')">Gantry</div>
<div class="accordion-content" data-ng-class="{'show-content':uiCtrl.showGantry}">test</div>
```

When I call `toggleContent` method via `ng-click`, everything works fine then.
But when the call comes from `LeafletMap directive` it runs `toggleContent` method and sets proper boolean values to public properties in `UIController` but `ng-class` doesn't update.

```
scope.uiCtrl.loadingMessage = 'test'; //it works correctly BTW
```

When I run `scope.$apply()` (just for test) inside `LeafletMap` after calling `toggleContent` method, then ng-class was updated, but it caused errors like `apply already in progress` of course.

Why `ng-class` doesn't update when I call appropriate controller method within directive?

### EDIT

```
scope.$root.$on('gantry-details', (event: IAngularEvent, message: any) =>
{
    this._timeout(() =>
    {
        scope.uiCtrl.toggleContent('showGantry');
    });
});
```

Using `timeout` solved the problem.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but you could refactor your toggle content function to use 'map'

Comment: Hey @pavon147, if you are able to provide a jsfiddle example reproducing the issue that would be great.

Comment: toggleContent(commandToExecute) { this.commands = this.commands.map(function(map) { return command === commandToExecute ? true : false; }); }

Comment: @Rorschach120 thanks! @Kaloyan Kosev - when I run `toggleContent` in `link` from directive but after `timeout` not from `scope.$root.on...` it worked, so the problem comes from that listener...

Comment: Oops I meant function(command) ... On phone